# Auto appearing horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

```
#wrapper
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 40px 100px 0 100px;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to do this: 
How to appear horizontal scroll at the bottom of container if the width of container > 100 %?
Tried to use max-width, was not any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the horizontal `overflow` of this element to `auto`.

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/SebE5/)

```
#container {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried this one also before, no result again. On my web page i add images width command float:left. When the number of images almost more 7 the last image appears at the bottom.

I want the set every images in one line

Comment: So that's a totally different question than the one you've posted. Anyway use `white-space: nowrap` like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/SebE5/1/